# Should questions on aviation regulations be posted on aviation, law or travel Stack Exchange website?

Tags: discussion, scope

Should questions on aviation regulations be posted on aviation, law or travel Stack Exchange website?

Assume the  question is of interest to commercial airplane passengers, e.g. [For which planes do Federal Aviation Administration (FAA) regulations apply?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/151117/1810)

Answer (score 3):

The aviation and law stack exchanges can decide for themselves whether they want to accept such questions. On the face of it the topic seems reasonable for both. But you'd have to ask them, not us.

It certainly doesn't feel to me like an on-topic question for travel, though, at least in the general case. What's really relevant for a traveller is what their carrier allows, that will be informed by the regulations but in many cases more restrictive.

The only case I can (immediately) see where I'd consider this on-topic here is if you (/your friend/family member/etc) have a pilot's license and are considering flying yourself in a privately-owned/rented plane, and trying to determine whether the regulations apply to such private flights. Even in that case, I'd still suspect the other two stacks are more likely to have the relevant knowledge.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thanks, how about this use case: Travelers sometime look for regulations that apply to their planes (e.g. regulations pertaining to portable batteries in carry-on luggage), as a result might be interested to know where Federal Aviation Administration (FAA) regulations apply regulations apply.

Comment: To me that seems like they're asking the wrong question. It doesn't matter what's permitted by the regulations, it matters what the carrier allows. That is often (and I suspect your batteries example is a case where this specifically applies, although I'll admit I haven't checked) more restrictive than the FAA regulations.

Comment: Airlines sometimes refer to FAA regulations, e.g. https://www.united.com/ual/en/us/fly/travel/baggage/dangerous.html , so I believe that'd still be of interest to travelers to know where FAA regulations apply.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt if it said they apply FAA regulations only where they're legally required to (without a clear definition of what that includes), I'd see your point.